# SQL server entity reference between tables

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, azure-sql-database

I am new to SQL server and I am trying to learn the power of SQL :)

I need help with understanding how different tables can interact with one and other within the same database. I know that an entity can have a foreign key with a reference to an attribute of a different table. But how can I have one table with a reference to many different tables?

Lets take an example. I have a simple database with a Car table, Bike table and Boat table. Each of these tables have the attributes Id, Make, Model and Year. Now I want to add a Service table with the attributes IdService and ServiceNote to the database where I want each IdService to refere to a specific car, bike or boat from one of the three tables.

How can I do this? Please see the simple diagram I have attached for better understanding.

[image: Simple diagram]

Comment: Instead of a separate table for bike, boat, and car -- I would probably suggest trying to put it in 1 table -- especially since your 3 tables contain the same information, or nearly the same.  Maybe something like inventory or vehicle.  The inventory table would have vehicle type (bike, boat, car), make, model, year, etc.  Then Service just simply references the ID of the inventory table.

Answer (score 0):

You just include the columns you want.  Here is one method:

```
create table services (
    servicesid int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    bikeid int references bikes(bikeid),
    boatid int references boats(boatid),
    carid int references cars(carid),
    servicenote nvarchar(max),
    check ((bikeid is not null and boatid is null and carid is null) or
           (bikeid is null and boatid is not null and carid is null) or
           (bikeid is null and boatid is null and carid is not null)
          )
);
```

This structure allows you to properly declare the foreign key relationships.  The `check` constraint also ensures that each row only talks to one entity.

Some databases support inheritance in tables.  That would allow you to declare a "super" type for bikes, boats, and cars, all sharing the same id.  Although you can do that without inheritance, it is a bit cumbersome.  For a handful of connections, explicit references are often sufficient (although wasteful in the sense that the empty values do take up space on the data pages).